# Proving $n < 2^n$ by Cantor's theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So we know Cantor's Theorem is of course.

For any set $S$, the power set $P(S)$ has a strictly greater cardinality,

$\iff \#S < \#P(S)$.

We seek to prove $n < 2^n$ using this information.

I was shown this proof by an instructor (this might actually be the proof of the theorem itself) but I was stuck on proving the part that it can only be an injection and not a bijection. I annotate the area that confuses me and an explanation would be hugely helpful.

I already know that this is provable by induction and is probably the better way but that is beyond the scope of my question at this time.

---

Suppose we have a set $S$ such that $\#S = n$. We know that $\#P(S) = 2^n$.

To prove $n < 2^n$, we aim to show there exists strictly an injection $f: S \rightarrow P(S)$.

Consider the function $f(x) = \{x\}$.

To prove it is injective, assume

$f(x_1) = f(x_2)$

$\implies \{x_1\} = \{x_2\}$

$\implies x_1 = x_2$, therefore $f$ is injective.

Now we seek to prove it is not a bijection, by showing that such a bijection is impossible.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction we do have such a bijection $g: S \rightarrow P(S)$.

Let $K = \{ x \in S \mid x \notin g(x)\}$

> I'm confused as to what this is? The set containing elements of $S$ that... don't get mapped to $P(S)$? Is that even possible? Is that the point?

Observe that $K \in P(S)$ since $K \subseteq S$.

$\exists z \in S$ such that $g(z) = K$, since $g$ is onto.

$z \in K$

$\iff z \notin g(z)$

$\iff z \notin K$

> What happened here?

This is a contradiction so no such bijection $g$ exists. Thus $f$ must strictly be an injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualize it with the following example:

Let $n=3$, and define $g$ by 
$$1\mapsto \{1,2\}$$
$$2\mapsto \{3\}$$
$$3\mapsto \{1,3\}$$

Then, $K$ is the set of all $x\in S$ such that $x\notin g(x)$.

$$1\in \{1,2\}$$
$$2\notin \{3\}$$
$$3\in \{1,3\}$$

Thus, $K=\{2\}$. Now, as $K$ is also an element of $P(S)$, there should be an element $x\in S$ such that $g(x)=K$.

If $x\in K=g(x)$, by the definition of $K$, $x\notin K$. Contradiction.

If $x\notin K=g(x)$, by the definition of $K$, $x\in K$. Contradiction.

This is like the classical example, the set of all sets that does not contain itself as an element.